# Apply ulimit globally on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ulimit

I need to apply "ulimit -s 256" to any system thread. Is there any way to achieve this under Ubuntu Server?

Comment: What about /etc/security/limits.conf ? Doesn't it solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set user limits via `pam_limits` in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. See `man limits.conf` for informations about this file.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 12.04 */etc/security/limits.conf* does not appear to be read unless the following is added to */etc/pam.d/common-session*.

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

Even then, it's not clear to me if it is picked up for programs started by upstart scripts.

Comment: Note that there is also a commented line in `/etc/pam.d/su`: `# session    required   pam_limits.so`.